# Texture baking noise reduction with filmic-blender, clamping does not work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, noise-reduction

I have a house interior model which I want to use both for high-quality renders and for converting to a web viewer. I've been experimenting with filmic-blender, and love the effect on the renders. My sun lamp is at strength 300, background at 25.

I now want to bake diffuse lightmap textures (cycles bake diffuse direct+indirect). The textures are very bright, which is expected since blender does not apply the logarithmic tone mapping on baking. There are also a lot of fireflies though, even at insane sample settings (16000)

I have tried to set Clamp Direct and Clamp Indirect, but these don't seem to have any effect on bakes. Does anybody know the reason for this, and better yet, does anyone have other ideas for reducing the noise?

Comment: The filter "Selective gaussian blur" from GIMP does miracles for lightmap post-processing.

Answer (score 1):

Applying simple 2D image filters for lightmap textures does not work for many reasons, primarily because it will ignore things like adjacent faces, edges, difference of shapes between faces, and other features of the 3D mesh.

But **you can use the Batch Bake Blender Addon**, it can use a **texture noise reduction ("denoising") solution that consider the mesh** geometry of the texture:

[image]

It's available at
https://noevu.com/#batch-bake

Blender Artists post: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?443843